# OData V4: How to sum individual $count values

Tags: odata

I have the following OData V4 query:

```
.../odata/Locations/?$select=Id&$filter=(Id eq 9bb29421-5160-4546-b87f-a78c0074f5c5 or Id eq 8b2a9727-a642-446e-b992-76c6d1584989)&$expand=Assets($select=Id;$filter=ParentAssetId eq null;$expand=Jobs($select=Id;$count=true;$top=0))
```

with the following, as expected, result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": ".../odata/$metadata#Locations(Id,Assets(Id,Jobs(Id)))",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "8b2a9727-a642-446e-b992-76c6d1584989",
            "Assets": [
                {
                    "Id": "540d0855-aa1c-4e94-9d0b-332c99ec00b6",
                    "Jobs@odata.count": 2,
                    "Jobs": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "6dcaa0e8-fc31-4d86-9f1a-a64300f8815c",
                    "Jobs@odata.count": 1,
                    "Jobs": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "db4cf86b-9f42-4a99-b7b4-a64300f8c740",
                    "Jobs@odata.count": 1,
                    "Jobs": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "9bb29421-5160-4546-b87f-a78c0074f5c5",
            "Assets": [
                {
                    "Id": "08a2a046-86c1-41a9-b2b1-a7ac007bed64",
                    "Jobs@odata.count": 1,
                    "Jobs": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "2b76dad1-4058-4261-8a40-a7af00cb8bd5",
                    "Jobs@odata.count": 1,
                    "Jobs": []
                },
                {
                    "Id": "3a5472a1-68c4-4dc4-b2cd-a797007b0068",
                    "Jobs@odata.count": 2,
                    "Jobs": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I sum the **Jobs@odata.count** values and return a single value: **8**?

I have tried some *&$apply=aggregate(Assets/Jobs@odata.count with sum as Total)* but it is an incorrect syntax :(

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the query perspective and count the Jobs from the beginning:

```
.../odata/Jobs/$count/?$expand=Asset($select=LocationId)&$filter=Asset/LocationId in (9bb29421-5160-4546-b87f-a78c0074f5c5, 8b2a9727-a642-446e-b992-76c6d1584989)
```